# React redux mapStateToProps is called twice

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have question regarding to mapStateToProps function. I have code something like :

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    console.log(state);
    return {
       items: state.items
    }
}
```

And console log prints me {} and {something: Array[2]}.

It looks like mapStateTo Props is called twice. Why it behave like that ?
What could be a reason ?

Regards

Comment: Because at different parts of your application two state changes are initiated.

Comment: there is only one component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing details about how much code you have or what it does this is just an educated guess:

As your application gets started the state is initialized as empty, so `{}`. After that something dispatches a state change with the value `something`.

Comment: far enough for me. Thank you